# Modify native/default resolution of VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I'm working on testing some provisioning tools which involves viewing the OOBE in Windows repeatedly. This of course means I cannot install the Guest Additions and I cannot change the resolution from Windows.  I'm hoping there is some way to attach a different virtual display. I have tried both VMSVGA and VboxSVGA. I have also tried the 3D Acceleration checkbox. I also tried setting the Video Memory to the max of 256MB. No matter what, it has the same resolution and cuts things off in testing.

Is there a way to do what I want?

[image]

Comment: This of course means I cannot install the Guest Additions    ........   You must install Guest Additions to change default resolution in VBOX.  So you must work with VBOX the way it is.

Comment: So you must work with VBOX the way it is ............ if you say so.

Comment: What exactly do you want? The problem is not very clear.

Comment: I don't know how to make it much more clear. I want to change the resolution. But changing it in Windows with the guest additions is not an option. I want to change it before that point. On a physical machine, no matter what size monitor you plug in, you can do Windows setup without things getting cut off. That's really all I want. I want to fix the screenshot above. I don't want screen elements to be cut off.

Comment: @THEJOATMON Oh whoops, I'm not sure when I misread that it was PE instead of oobe. If it's regular windows 11, there's no reason you couldn't preinstall the guest additions into your image, but the method for that depends on what you're testing

Comment: I'm actually testing alternatives to imaging, like provisioning packages, etc. So creating an image just so I can preload the Guest Additions, run sysprep, and get back to the OOBE is a bit counterintuitive. I guess I'll just deal with the crappy resolution/scaling. It's just frustrating that I can't specify a different sized virtual monitor or something. Seemed like a no-brainer to me, but I guess I'm crazy.

Comment: Can you just set a "monitor" size in pixels from the virtual box window > view > virtual screen > Resize to xy (and set scaling to the lowest)? Most systems aren't going to notice unless you have the guest additions drivers, but Win11 might - It's not something I can test

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately, it's all grayed out.